# How to remove duplicate's string input is : "aaa bbb ccc aaa cccc" output is: aaa bbb ccc using java script

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, ecmascript-6

I FACED THIS QUESTION ORACLE

And One more Question: if i passed 
ex-1 : input is 123 output - 00123
ex-2 : input is 23 output - 00023 insert zero's at before input - length

And One more Question:If i given
Ex-1: input : january february output:  january february march
Ex-1: input : march april output:  march april may

Please help thanks for helping

I tried for loops and split , But interviewer said use hash-maps hash-table i don't have idea , 
 Please explain 
Please stay tune i posted interview questions its very helpful for experienced person's

Comment: What was your solution?

Comment: so you have the first part of looping and splitting, and as they told you,  you use a map.object to not get dupes....

Answer (score 1):

Try following

```js
var str = "aaa bbb ccc aaa ccc";
var map = {};
str.split(" ").forEach(function(word) {
  map[word] = true; // enter the word in map (overrides dupes - have unique key)
});
console.log(Object.keys(map).join(" ")); // join all keys to return string
```

Comment: Thanks Lot .. can please explain, where i can this this type of programs

Comment: @VeereshKoppula - Well for knowledge, refer to MDN. To build algorithms, you will have to practice. :)

Comment: @VeereshKoppula Each word is used as an unique key for the map.So when you add the same word twice, nothing really happens. And at the end you just output all these keys.

Answer (score 0):

[`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) basically does the same as nikhils object:

```js
var str = "aaa bbb ccc aaa ccc";
var result = [...new Set(str.split(' '))].join(' ');
console.log(result);
```

`Set` removes all duplicates. `[...new Set()]` converts the set to an array.